# When removing multiple items from an ArrayList, why is is better to use a while loop instead of a decrementing for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I am reading a few programming books and doing online lessons right now (so no teacher to ask) and I have seen in each of them the same thing is being said. In each one it says that when you are removing multiple items from an ArrayList in Java, that you should not use a for loop but a while loop instead. I understand why you would not use

`for (int i = 0; i < arylst.size(); i++) 
 {...}`

but when I try to do it like this

`for (int i = arylst.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
 {...}`

it seems to work fine. Could this lead to issues in some cases? Why is this not the correct way to do it?

Comment: I have seen this in 4 places and none of them address the idea of a decrementing for loop. They just say not to use the for loop and that the correct way is to use a while loop.

Comment: MUCH more context would really help this question :)

Comment: Seems like a nonsensical advice. Better in which regard? Book, page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing incorrect about a decrementing for loop.

The only issues it can and usually does lead to is bugs because there is a symbol missing when written. It's not the 90% use case of the for loop so it might not be as intuitive for everyone to write and therefore leads to bugs easier.
This is why the while loop is preferred in teaching books.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `for-each` loop to remove elements from `List` or `ArrayList`, you will face `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`. You need to use `java.util.Iterator`.

Here is an example:-

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=1; i<=10; i++){
            list.add(i);
        }
        System.out.println("list (before) = "+list);

        // removing the even elements
        System.out.println("even numbers have been removed");
        Iterator<Integer> iterator =list.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            Integer num= iterator.next();
            if(num%2==0){
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }       
        System.out.println("list (after) = "+list);     
    }

}
```

Please have a look at this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html

It is said that:

> Note that Iterator.remove is the only safe way to modify a collection
>   during iteration; the behavior is unspecified if the underlying
>   collection is modified in any other way while the iteration is in
>   progress.

#### Example using `for each` loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list= new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=1; i<=10; i++){
        list.add(i);
    }
    System.out.println("list (before) = "+list);

    // removing the even elements
    System.out.println("even numbers have been removed");

    for(Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ){
        Integer num = iterator.next();
        if(num%2==0){
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }       
    System.out.println("list (after) = "+list);     
}
```

Comment: @MakPo May I know why this answer is not a solution to the problem that you are facing?

Comment: I wasn't the one that downvoted it. It might be correct but I don't really understand what an iterator is or the `ConcurrentModificationException`. I'm looking it up on the Java documentation right now.

Comment: @MakPo Could you have a look at the additions to my answer?

Comment: I will just add that, regardless the type of loop you are using (whether `for` or `while` the safest way to modify a list while iterating it is to use and `iterator`. So it is possible to use a `for` loop with an `iterator` inside it

Comment: @MakPo I will advice you always to use `iterator` when you need to modify a list while iterating it

Comment: @SanjeevSaha if you don't mind, I would like to edit your answer with an example using the `for` loop

Comment: @tfosra It's OK. Please go ahead.

Comment: The example at the end of this post isn't using a `for each` loop, but a for loop and an iterator, the title should be changed.

Comment: @MakPo Why don't you accept the answer so that readers may know which of the answers is correct otherwise they don't have a clue.

Comment: @Sanjeev Saha I marked the other one as correct because it more correctly answered the underlying question. Your response is great as well and I learned about a new concept that I've not seen before, but it doesn't really answer the question.